# Android FragmentPagerAdapter, getItems, instantiateItem is deprectaed

Tags: android

Please see in the image below what can i do to change listed deprecated functions.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the [deprecation method in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter):

> This class is deprecated. Switch to [`ViewPager2`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) and use [`FragmentStateAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter) instead.

The [Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2 documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) details the exact steps needed to convert your layout, adapter, and integrations with `TabLayout` to `ViewPager2`.